# Convert 8 depth single channel (YUV) image to 24 depth RGB(3 Channels) image

Tags: opencv, rgb

How convert one channel YUV image (first channel - Y are used) to 24 depth RGB image? I asks, because i must display it using gtk+ interface and gtk supports only 24 depth RGB image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are actually starting from, a single-channel grayvalue image or a three-channel YUV image of which the second and third channel are full of zeros. If you have a single-channel 8-bit image to start with, you can use `cvtColor(source_mat,destination_mat,CV_GRAY2RGB)` to convert to 24-bit RGB. If you are starting from a 3-channel 24-bit YUV image with two channels full of zeros, you can use the `split()` function to get the Y channel out of it, then convert that as described above.

Comment: The code: IplImage *new2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(diff), 32, 3); cvCvtColor(diff, new2, CV_GRAY2RGB); results with following error: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.depth() == dst.depth()) in cvCvtColor, file /usr/src/packages/BUILD/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3172
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /usr/src/packages/BUILD/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3172: error: (-215) src.depth() == dst.depth() in function cvCvtColor

Comment: The diff matrix is 8-bit single channel image.

Comment: I obtained Y channel with cvSetImageCOI(img, 1); cvCopy(img1, img2, 0); . I created the img2 image with: img2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img1), 8, 1);